# Jquery Sortables last "dragged" item

Tags: jquery, sortables

Sorry, back agin

How can I get at the "last" sortable item.  I am dragging from one list 2 another but I need/want to append the "length" to the last dragged item which may not be the last item in the "dropped" list - hope you understand.

some idea of code

```
    $j(function() {
        $j("#id_section_layout").sortable({
        connectWith: '.colunm,.layoutcolunm,#layoutbin',
        helper: 'clone',
        receive: function(event, ui) {
        $j("#id_section_layout .content_options").children().show();
        var val= $j("#id_section_layout .content_options").length;
// .. I want to append val to the LAST dragged/dropped item
//.. If I do this it is always to the "last" item in the list which may not be the last dragged item -
             $j("#id_section_layout .content_options").last().append(val);
//.. So is there a way to get the last dragged item?
        }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `receive` handler you can use [`ui.item`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/), there are several elements available off the `ui` object your function receives:

> - **ui.helper** - the current helper element (most often a clone of the item)
> - **ui.position** - current position of the helper
> - **ui.offset** - current absolute position of the helper
> - **ui.item** - the current dragged element
> - **ui.placeholder** - the placeholder (if you defined one)
> - **ui.sender** - the sortable where the item comes from (only exists if you move from one connected list to another)

Comment: Thanks Nick, nearly there but prob. is I don't think I need append, as that then just "increases" the numbers i.e. 1 on the second (starting at 0),12 on the third, 123 on the fourth etc...